# jQuery's load() in Semantic UI API

Tags: php, jquery, api, load, semantic-ui

This is my Semantic UI API-Setup so far:

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'search'        : '/api/search.api.php?query={value}'
};

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.searchterms input')
     .api({
         action       : 'search',
         stateContext : '.ui.input',
         minCharacters : 3
     });

});
```

My `search.api.php` fires an mysql query and the results should be loaded `<div id="#results">`. As template engine, I use [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), so the `search.api.php` includes these lines:

```
foreach($results AS $aresult) {
    $smarty->display('single_result.tpl');
}
```

Now my question: How can I use jQuery's load() to deal with it? It should be something like

```
$("#results").load(...???);
```

Comment: $("#results").load(your url, {data you want to send on server});

Comment: For sure, I know the syntax of load(). But how can i force it to interact with Semantic UI API?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution and it works fine. Take a look at these snippets

Javascript:

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'search'        : '/api/search.api.php?query={value}'
};

$.fn.api.settings.successTest = function(response) {
    if(response && response.success) {
        return response.success;
    }
    return false;
};

$('.searchterms input')
    .api({
        action       : 'search',
        stateContext:  '.ui.input',
        minCharacters : 3,
        successTest: function(response) {
            return response.success || false;
        },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            $("#items").html(response.items);
            $(".results").html(response.data);
        }
    })
;
```

As you can see, the solution can be achieved with the callback `onComplete`. And, important, instead of using `load()` I used html() to simply replace the html-code in the `<div class="results">` area:

```
onComplete: function(response) {
    $("#items").html(response.items);
    $(".results").html(response.data);
}
```

PHP (search.api.php):

```
$output='';
foreach($results AS $result) {
    $smarty->assign("result", $result);
    $output .= $smarty->fetch('single_result.tpl');
}
$response=json_encode(array(
  'success' => true,
  'message' => 'Okay',
  'items'   => $entries_found,
  'data'    => $output
));

echo $response;
```

In search.in.php it's important not to use `$smarty->display()`, but `$smarty->fetch()` and catch the result to a variable `$output`. This variable can be returned.